# Visual Studio SSDT Database project (.sqlproj) build - generate .dacpac using CLI without MSBUILD (msbuild.exe)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, dacpac, dotnet-cli

Looks as though `dotnet CLI` has no support for Database projects (.sqlproj) according to this: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8546

in my case `dotnet build` fails with the following error:

> C:...*.Database.sqlproj(59,3):
> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.301\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets"
> was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration
> "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.301\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets"
> is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Needless to say, the solution compiles and generates .dacpac via Build in Visual Studio. I need this to work from command line. Do I have any solutions other than msbuild.exe? Perhaps some lovely nuget package out there that could help?

Comment: I think you can just download build tool for VS2019. It is a lightweight build tool that integrates various modules independently of VS. It's just a command tool.

Comment: which tool is it?

Comment: Build Tool for VS2019

Comment: Build Tool for VS is more like the form of `dotnet.exe` and it is more suitable for you to build related projects on the build server. If you have any concern, please feel free to let us know:)

Comment: Any update for this in 2023?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to make it work as described in this article: https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/05/11/ssdt-dacpac-netcore.html

It requires a special type of .NET Standard Visual Studio project - `MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj` (nuget download), which copies scripts from the Database project when compiled.

here's my build_database.cmd code:

```
SET db_project=Database.Build
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-script  
cd %db_project%
dotnet build
dotnet-script Program.csx
```

And a C# script (Program.csx), which creates and deploys a .dacpac using `Microsoft.SqlServer.DACFx` nuget package:

```
#r "nuget: Microsoft.SqlServer.DACFx, 150.4769.1"
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac;

var dbName = "SampleDatabase";
var connectionString = $"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog={dbName};Integrated Security=True;";
var dacpacLocation = Directory.GetFiles(@".\bin", "Database.Build.dacpac", 
                                                           SearchOption.AllDirectories)[0];
var dbPackage = DacPackage.Load(dacpacLocation);
var services = new DacServices(connectionString);

services.Deploy(dbPackage, dbName, true);
```

this approach is fully automated and can be used in either CI or local dev environment and, apparently, is also cross-platform (albeit I've only tested on Windows).
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have any solutions other than msbuild.exe? Perhaps some lovely
> nuget package out there that could help?

**Actually**, there is no other build tool to build Database projects except msbuild.exe. So you have to use `msbuild.exe`.

**Since** VS2017, `msbuild.exe` has a separate version that does not depend on VS IDE called **Build Tool for VS**. And it is the build command line that integrates with the VS Workload environment.

So I think you want a lightweight build tool on build server rather than the huge VS IDE, if so, you should download it.

**Suggestion**

**1)** download [build tool for VS2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) under **All Downloads**-->**Tools for Visual Studio 2019**-->**Build Tool for Visual Studio 2019**.

[image]

**2)** remember to select the corresponding workload **Data storage and processing build tools**

[image]

When you finish it, you can build your database project with it.

Answer (score 0):

My method:

1. Install Visual Studio Build Tools 2019

Include "Data storage and processing build tools" workflow **and .NET Framework 4.6.1 targeting pack** (individual component)