# How can I specify path of msbuild when running "dotnet msbuild" command?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, command-line-interface

I want to run "dotnet msbuild" command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-msbuild

However, I want to be able to specify the exact path to msbuild like: `dotnet C:\name\msbuild.exe`. (Adding it to the path is not an option)

How can I do this?

Comment: why do you need to specify the path?. just go the main project directory and run dotnet build or dotnet msbuild

Comment: I want to control the version of msbuild being used

Comment: You can just run that particular msbuild directly: `C:\name\msbulid.exe`. No need to involve `dotnet`. But really, this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you trying to use a specific msbuild?

Comment: I am running my app in a windows server container. It does an older version of msbuild and I need the latest one, otherwise my build fails for some reason I dont get

Comment: `Dotnet msbuild` does not have an option to specify the msbuild version. And if you want to use different versions of msbuild, you could use `Build Tool for VS2017(msbuild 15.0) or  Build Tool for VS0219(msbuild 16.0)` which is a lightweight build command-line tool that can be thrown away from the vs installation. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62549989/12450747). And then you can call one of them based on requirements to use the specific version-----------`msbuild xxx.xxproj -t:build`.

Answer (score 3):

> However, I want to be able to specify the exact path to msbuild like:
> dotnet C:\name\msbuild.exe. (Adding it to the path is not an option)

**Actually**, `dotnet msbuild` does not have an option to specify which version of MSBuild to use. And `MSBuild of dotnet.exe` is updated with the Version of the `NET Core SDK`.

**And as far as I know**, the latest `Net Core 3.+ SDK` uses `MSBuild 16.+` which is the latest MSBuild. So if you want to use the latest MSBuild on your windows server container, you should [install the latest version of Net Core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download).

**Note**: In this way, you can only use `MSBuild 16.+`which supports building the old projects.

**Besides**, you can also install [Build Tool for VS2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019) or [Build Tool for VS2017](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202017) to build your projects on your windows server container. Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62531943/visual-studio-ssdt-database-project-sqlproj-build-generate-dacpac-using-cl/62549989#62549989).

It is a lightweight build command-line tool that can be thrown away from the vs installation. When you start to install it, you need to select the related Build workload.

**Build Tool for VS2017** is `MSBuild 15` while **Build Tool for VS2019** is `MSBuild 16`. You can install both of them.

**Then** after you finish installing it, you should **launch** Build Tool and then you can build them with command line `msbuild xxx.xxproj -t:target`.